# android linearlayout baseline align

Tags: android, eclipse, user-interface

I have 3 imageviews but since they overlap i wont make them clickable, i want make buttons on top of each imageview(but smaller).

I know in `RelativeLayout` there is easy way out using `align_baseline` but it is very important that i use `LinearLayout` for these images because they use `layout_weight`

And its important that button is connected with imageview, not just appearing on top of it

And here is my code it might help

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
     ...
      <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"        
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:layout_above="@+id/twitter"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
                <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/imgDis"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_width="300dp"
             android:layout_height="120dp"
             android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp"
             android:background="@drawable/img1" />

                  <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgCal"
             android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/img2"
            android:paddingLeft="25dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgDe"
             android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"

            android:background="@drawable/img3" />

        </LinearLayout>
        ...
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I don't get your question

Comment: how to make button on top of imageview

Answer (score 1):

put the image in another linear layout vertical and place that layout inside your mainlayout and give the wieght to this linearlayout instead of the image

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer, while using `weight` you must define `0dp` to height/width to view as per case.

You want `Button` on every `Imageview` something like below?

I tried, check below xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="6" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="button first" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgDis"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.5"
            android:background="@drawable/logo" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="button first" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgCal"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.5"
            android:background="@drawable/logo"
            android:paddingLeft="25dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="button first" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgDe"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.5"
            android:background="@drawable/logo" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```